# Using arc4random to generate ten random numbers

Tags: ios, swift, random, firebase, arc4random

I am using `arc4random` to generate 10 random numbers so I can then query firebase to get the questions that contain the randomly generated numbers. The problem is that I don't want any number to appear more than once so then there are not duplicate questions. Current code below...

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class QuestionViewController: UIViewController {

    var amountOfQuestions: UInt32 = 40

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // Use a for loop to get 10 questions
        for _ in 1...10{
            // generate a random number between 1 and the amount of questions you have
            let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(amountOfQuestions - 1)) + 1
            print(randomNumber)
            // The reference to your questions in firebase (this is an example from firebase itself)
            let ref = Firebase(url: "https://test.firebaseio.com/questions")
            // Order the questions on their value and get the one that has the random value
            ref.queryOrderedByChild("value").queryEqualToValue(randomNumber)
                .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
                    snapshot in
                    // Do something with the question
                    print(snapshot.key)
                })
        }
    }

    @IBAction func truepressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func falsePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not subtract 1 from amountOfQuestions

Comment: You can randomly remove each element from the original array if you don't want them to occur twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the total number of questions

```
let questionsCount = 100
```

you can generate a sequence of integers

```
var naturals = [Int](0..<questionsCount)
```

Now given the quantity of unique random numbers you need

```
let randomsCount = 10
```

that of course should not exceed the total number of questions

```
assert(randomsCount <= questionsCount)
```

you can build your list of unique integers

```
let uniqueRandoms = (1..<randomsCount).map { _ -> Int in
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(naturals.count)))
    return naturals.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

Comment: Since you don't remove the random objects you pick from the array, isn't it possible to repeat the same value? Seems to me the line `return naturals[index]` should be changed to `return naturals.removeAtIndex(index)`. That will remove and return an object.

Comment: @appzYourLife as Duncan C has already noted this will not prevent a random number from appearing more than once. Just change the number of questions to 10 and you will notice it

Comment: You are right! Let me fix it as soon as I come home. And thank you!

Comment: Fixed via iPhone. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

You can have an array to store the value you want to random with, in your case, [1,2,3....10], and then use arc4random to get the random index of any value inside (0..9), get the value and remove it from array. Then you will never get the same number from the array.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to generating the random number on the client and requesting a question at that specified number, you could download the entire array of questions and shuffle the array.  GameKit provides a built-in method to shuffle the array.

```
import GameKit

// ...

let ref = Firebase(url: "https://test.firebaseio.com/questions")
// Order the questions on their value and get the one that has the random value
ref.queryOrderedByChild("value")
    .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        // Shuffle your array
        let shuffledQuestions = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(snapshot)
        // Store your array somewhere and iterate through it for the duration of your game
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate random numbers and store each number in an `NSArray`. However, when you append it to the array you can check if the array already contains that number.

For example:

```
for _ in 1...10 {
let amountOfQuestions: UInt32 = 40
var intArray: [Int] = []
let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(amountOfQuestions - 1)) + 1

if intArray.contains(randomNumber) {

    repeat {
        randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(amountOfQuestions - 1)) + 1
    } while intArray.contains(randomNumber)

    if !intArray.contains(randomNumber) {
        intArray.append(randomNumber)
    }


} else {
    intArray.append(randomNumber)
}

    print(intArray)
}
```

After that you can make a FireBase request with your uniquely generated integers. I hope I was able to help :).

Answer (score 0):

Create unsorted Array of ten random Int 0..99

```
var set = Set<Int>()
while set.count < 10 {
    let num = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    set.insert(num)
}
let arr = Array(set)
```